# azure function Failed error message with no node.js errors logging

Tags: node.js, azure

In the Azure Function portal log I only get this Failed message, but no other node.js errors.  Why?

[Error] Executed 'Functions.BlobTriggerJS1' (Failed, Id=357b9990-7a36-4e48-a872-979c562de568)

I even tried putting context.log in my function like this code below.  nothing gets logged. I need to debug in the portal because I need to see why function won't convert an upload PDF blob to images.  Need that trigger. But I don't know what is causing the error.
Thanks,
Donnie

```
pdf2img.convert(input, function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
            context.log(err);
             context.done()

            }
        else {
            context.log(info);

            context.done()
        }
    });
```

2018-09-14T22:51:14  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-09-14T22:52:08.633 [Information] Executing 'Functions.BlobTriggerJS1' (Reason='New blob detected: pdfblobs/sharonsparks_5pages.pdf', Id=357b9990-7a36-4e48-a872-979c562de568)
2018-09-14T22:52:18.805 [Information] JavaScript blob trigger function processed blob 
 Name: sharonsparks_5pages.pdf 
 Blob Size: 305669 Bytes
2018-09-14T22:52:18.813 [Information] dirD:\home\site\wwwroot\BlobTriggerJS1
2018-09-14T22:52:19.030 [Error] Executed 'Functions.BlobTriggerJS1' (Failed, Id=357b9990-7a36-4e48-a872-979c562de568)

Answer (score -1):

I figured how how to use Azure Functions extension in VSCode, to see debugging information.

Comment: Might explain this further